# Pandas при чтении CSV файла не парсит числа, содержащие запятую в качестве десятичного разделителя

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, csv, dataframe

Файл csv сохранен в LibreOffice из excel файла. При стандартной загрузке:

```
map_data = pd.read_csv('map.csv', sep=';')
```

в нужном столбце получаются данные типа - dtype: object
Если попытаться их перевести в числовые:

```
pd.to_numeric(map_data['Dist_Loc'])
```

выдается следующая ошибка:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "3,095" at position 0
```

Если попытаться перевести в числовые другим способом:

```
map_data['Dist_Loc'].astype(np.float)
```

Тоже возникает ошибка:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6,157'
```

Comment: pandas (как и почти все остальные) ожидает точку (а не запятую) в качестве разделителя дробной части. Можно изменить locale на русскую ([`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')` + `df.applymap(locale.atof)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22137890/5812238)), тогда, вероятно, pandas будет принимать запятую в качестве разделителя.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если `6,157` - это `6.157`, т.е. `,` - десятичный разделитель, то можно воспользоваться параметром `decimal`

```
df = pd.read_csv('map.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
```

если `,` это разделитель разрядов и `6,157` - это `6157`, то можно воспользоваться параметром `thousands`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('map.csv', sep=';', thousands=',')
```

[Ссылка на документацию...](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Pandas также замечательно [читает напрямую из Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Comment: Десятичный разделитель. Помогло, большое человеческое спасибо.